# How to create Spring boot Application images in docker

Tags: docker

I have created a Spring boot Application.
Now i want to create a docker images for it and run it as docker container.

Answer (score 0):

the most simple way is to add the jar to the container and run it using docker-compose

you can use the following docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8

WORKDIR opt
ADD app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

and the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: .
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
     - /app/src/main/resources/static:/opt/static #should match the actual path
```

you can later add a `db` service and etc

all files should be reside in the same folder and the path in the volumes should match the prj

a more complex methods can be achieved using

- download the project source code using git to the docker and run mvn to build the jar, takes a long time
- download a production jar from git

using those appraoches the container is self deployable and don't need to maintain the docker prj when the source code changes

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, good afternoon or good night!

Well... to create an image of your Spring Boot application, I recommend creating a file called `Dockerfile` at the root of your project.

After that, just insert the following settings in your `Dockerfile` file:

```
#Image of the application execution package in question
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim
FROM maven:3.2-jdk-8

#Creating application directory
RUN mkdir /app

#Creating application directory
WORKDIR /app

#Copy the .jar to the working directory
COPY target/<NAME_PROJECT>.jar /app

#Port configuration
EXPOSE <EXTERNAL_PORT>:<INTERNAL_PORT>

#Command to run the application
CMD ["java","-jar","<NAME_PROJECT>.jar"]
```

After creating your Dockerfile, simply run the following command to create your Docker image from the Spring Boot application:

```
docker build -t <NAME_IMAGE> .
```

After creating the image, let's run a container from that image:

```
docker run -it -d –name <NAME_CONTAINER> -p <EXTERNAL_PORT>:<INTERNAL_PORT> <NAME_IMAGE>
```

Some observations:

I am assuming that you are using Java 8 to develop your application, as well as maven 3.2 to build it, so in the image declaration on the Dockerfile I put the relevant images for that. However, if you are developing your application with a different version of java and maven, I suggest that you are searching the Dockerhub repository for the image that is relevant to the version from which you developed your project. Below is the link taking you directly to search the images you want:

[Dockerhub Java](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags)

[Dockerhub maven](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven?tab=tags)

If you want to understand a little more about the impressive technology of Docker, just visit my blog and stay on top of many things about:

[Docker article](https://myblog.rplproject.com/artigo/3/Conhecendo%20o%20Docker)

[Learning to use the Dockerfile](https://rafaelspaesleme.wordpress.com/2019/08/10/aprendendo-a-usar-o-dockerfile/)

[Containers Docker](https://rafaelspaesleme.wordpress.com/2019/08/17/levantando-um-conteiner-docker/)

Another thing I recommend is that you give your project a `mvn clean install`, so that Dockerfile can find your application.

All of this I'm talking about, too, if you're developing your Spring application using maven and the execution file, the jar, otherwise, if you're using another way, just keep the Dockerfile logic according to your Spring project's configuration.